# computed array length breaks page rendering

Tags: knockout.js

I have a computed array variable and I've noticed that on occasion the page which accesses the 'length' attribute of the computed array will break with undefined error. This is presumably because the computed hasn't yet returned anything while the page is already being rendered.

Are there any known work-arounds for this?

Comment: Without including any of your code or any [way to reproduce this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this question will most likely get closed.

Comment: You can test whether the computed returns `undefined` before you try to take its length. You can also design the computed to ensure that the computed doesn't return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If your observable array has a name like `myArray`, you can simply do this:

```
if (myArray && myArray.length) {
   // here you're safe to access length
}
```

In JavaScript you can check that someting is defined in this way because js coalesces everything (but `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `false`, empty string and something I must be forgetting right now) to true.

If it's an observable array, you should check it in this way:

```
if (myArray() && myArray().length) {
   // here you're safe to access length
}
```